# how to insert data in fact table by using procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I tried to insert data into fact table from other dimension table by using procedure but could not do it.sometime it shows missing expression,sometimes it gives error statement ignored.

I tried by writing this query but it did not work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE final_upload_fact AS
  CURSOR finally IS
    SELECT p.clean_project_key,
         u.cconsultant_key,
         c.stage_company_key,
         t.time_key
    FROM   clean_project p
    INNER  JOIN clean_consultant u
    ON     p.clean_consultant_id = u.cldmch_id
    INNER  JOIN clean_company c
    ON     p.clean_company_id = c.stage_ldmch_id
    INNER  JOIN dim_time t
    ON     t.year = to_char(p.clean_estimated_end_date, 'yyyy')
    OR     t.year = to_char(p.clean_actual_end_date, 'yyyy');
BEGIN
  FOR k IN finally
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO fact
    (prjfinished_estimatedate,
     hig_qual_consultant,
     nooffeedbackless3,
     noprjoverrunmnth,
     fk1_dim_consultant_key,
     fk2_time_key,
     fk3_dim_project_key,
     fk4_dim_company_key)
    VALUES
    (SELECT COUNT(dim_project_key)
     FROM   dim_project
     WHERE  dim_project_estimated_end_date <= dim_actual_end_date, 
       SELECT MAX(dim_highest_quality)
     FROM   dim_consultant,
       SELECT COUNT(dim_feedbackvalue)
       FROM   dim_project
       WHERE  dim_feedbackvalue != 'N/A'
       AND    dim_feedbackvalue <= 3,  SELECT COUNT(dim_project_key)
               FROM   dim_project,
       k.cconsultant_key,
       k.time_key,
       k.clean_project_key,
       k.stage_company_key);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: There isn't a replace clause in the mysql create statement - are you trying to convert oracle to mysql or is the question wrongly tagged?

Comment: mysql is wrongly tagged.Ignore it

Comment: Have you tried to run that values clause standalone?

Comment: How are the subqueries in the values clause linked to the cursor? Currently, you're not referencing any of the fields in the k record in those subqueries, meaning that they'd be the same for all rows you're inserting. Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your subqueries don't have brackets around them in the `VALUES` clause.

When you refer to subqueries, you need to enclose them in brackets, which would make your code look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE final_upload_fact AS
  CURSOR finally IS
    SELECT p.clean_project_key,
           u.cconsultant_key,
           c.stage_company_key,
           t.time_key
    FROM   clean_project p
    INNER  JOIN clean_consultant u
    ON     p.clean_consultant_id = u.cldmch_id
    INNER  JOIN clean_company c
    ON     p.clean_company_id = c.stage_ldmch_id
    INNER  JOIN dim_time t
    ON     t.year = to_char(p.clean_estimated_end_date, 'yyyy')
    OR     t.year = to_char(p.clean_actual_end_date, 'yyyy');
BEGIN
  FOR k IN finally
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO fact
      (prjfinished_estimatedate,
       hig_qual_consultant,
       nooffeedbackless3,
       noprjoverrunmnth,
       fk1_dim_consultant_key,
       fk2_time_key,
       fk3_dim_project_key,
       fk4_dim_company_key)
    VALUES
      ((SELECT COUNT(dim_project_key)
        FROM   dim_project
        WHERE  dim_project_estimated_end_date <= dim_actual_end_date), 
       (SELECT MAX(dim_highest_quality)
        FROM   dim_consultant),
       (SELECT COUNT(dim_feedbackvalue)
        FROM   dim_project
        WHERE  dim_feedbackvalue != 'N/A'
        AND    dim_feedbackvalue <= 3),
       (SELECT COUNT(dim_project_key)
        FROM   dim_project),
       k.cconsultant_key,
       k.time_key,
       k.clean_project_key,
       k.stage_company_key);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

However, your code could be vastly simplified by moving the subqueries into the cursor, which would then remove the need to loop through the cursor, as you can do an insert-as-select.

Assuming your subqueries really don't have any correlation with the cursor you defined, you could rewrite the whole thing like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE final_upload_fact AS
    INSERT INTO fact
          (prjfinished_estimatedate,
           hig_qual_consultant,
           nooffeedbackless3,
           noprjoverrunmnth,
           fk1_dim_consultant_key,
           fk2_time_key,
           fk3_dim_project_key,
           fk4_dim_company_key)
    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(dim_project_key)
            FROM   dim_project
            WHERE  dim_project_estimated_end_date <= dim_actual_end_date) cnt_est_less_act_end_dt, 
           (SELECT MAX(dim_highest_quality)
            FROM   dim_consultant) max_highest_quality_consultant,
           (SELECT COUNT(dim_feedbackvalue)
            FROM   dim_project
            WHERE  dim_feedbackvalue != 'N/A'
            AND    dim_feedbackvalue <= 3) feedback_cnt,
           (SELECT COUNT(dim_project_key)
            FROM   dim_project) project_cnt,
           p.clean_project_key,
           u.cconsultant_key,
           c.stage_company_key,
           t.time_key
    FROM   clean_project p
    INNER  JOIN clean_consultant u
    ON     p.clean_consultant_id = u.cldmch_id
    INNER  JOIN clean_company c
    ON     p.clean_company_id = c.stage_ldmch_id
    INNER  JOIN dim_time t
    ON     t.year = to_char(p.clean_estimated_end_date, 'yyyy')
    OR     t.year = to_char(p.clean_actual_end_date, 'yyyy');
END final_upload_fact;
/
```

That way, you remove all the context switching between PL/SQL and SQL that your original procedure has (i.e. open the cursor in PL/SQL, switch to SQL to generate the execution plan, back to PL/SQL to request the next row, back to SQL to fetch the next row, back to PL/SQL to store the row in the record, back to SQL to insert the relevant data, back to PL/SQL to determine the end of the loop has been reached and therefore to request the next row, etc, etc).